# Hangfire .NET Core ExpirationManager Error Bogging Down Application and Connection Pool

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, hangfire, hangfire-sql

This began out of the blue about two days ago with no rhyme or reason and has been completely bogged down my `PG` instance. 
I have been getting a recurring constant `Hangfire` error message below that states it basically cannot connect to the `PG` instance because there are no more available connections.

**Things I have tried so far:**

- I have added this global attribute to my startup but it seems to be ignored as you can see by the attempt number on the below error message: GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 0 });
- I have attempted restart the PG instance but all the queries come right back from `Hangfire`
- I have attempted to restart the pods hosting the `Hangfire` environment
- I have cleared the failed jobs through the `Hangfire` API
- I reset the PG DB by truncating them all and resetting the `LastUpdatedId`
- If I stop the applications and restart the DB instance the constant calls seem to go away, so it leads me to believe that `Hangfire` is the problem and not the database but I am not 100% sure.

**Here is the constant recurring error message:**

```
Hangfire.PostgreSql.ExpirationManager[0]
      Error occurred during execution of 'SQL Records Expiration Manager' process. Execution will be retried (attempt #150) in 00:05:00 seconds.
Npgsql.NpgsqlException: Exception while reading from stream ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection timed out. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection timed out
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<Ensure>d__27.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<Ensure>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<DoReadMessage>d__147.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>d__146.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadExpecting>d__153`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<Execute>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteNonQuery>d__84.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)
   at Hangfire.PostgreSql.ExpirationManager.Execute(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Hangfire.PostgreSql.ExpirationManager.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.AutomaticRetryProcess.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
```

**Second Error Message (New as of 7/14/2020):**

```
Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler[0]
      Error occurred during execution of 'RecurringJobScheduler' process. Execution will be retried (attempt #10) in 00:01:38 seconds.
System.TimeoutException: SetRangeInHash experienced timeout while trying to execute transaction
   at Hangfire.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlConnection.SetRangeInHash(String key, IEnumerable`1 keyValuePairs)
   at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.TryScheduleJob(JobStorage storage, IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 recurringJob)
   at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.AutomaticRetryProcess.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
```

Comment: is it possible a firewall was put in place that blocks the port to postgress ?

Comment: @Jawad We checked that but the firewall remains unchanged from when it was previously working and we are able to hit the db